# What is the difference between Factor Analysis and Path Analysis in Structural Equation Modelling?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, psychometrics, lavaan

I am still a beginner in Structural Equation Modelling and I don't have a solid background in Statistics, so I apologize if my question is a bit naïve.

What I traditionally do when creating a Conceptual Model is that I run a Factor Analysis to see if any variables should be removed from the model, and then a Path Analysis to check the significance effect. However, I still do not understand the exact difference between the two, as I have seen some studies that only use factor analysis.
Here are for example the results of my model:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A path analysis has regressions and covariances between latent variables.

A factor analysis has only covariances.

It doesn't really matter what you call them. It's more important that you understand what you are doing, and why.